# Exchange SMTP authentication issue with spammers

Tags: exchange, smtp, spam

I have a single Exchange 2013 server with all the roles and it looks like it's being used by a botnet. It is sending mails every 10 minutes to a specific domain from a specific user.

It is not an open relay and actually they are being authenticated against our server. What I don't know is what they're being authenticated as. I'd assume that it is AD authentication but I can't be sure at the moment. You can see the packet capture on the picture below. The yellow highlighted section is the username/password fields (obviously filtered as I don't want any more spam :) )

[image]

The main question is, how do I find what they are authenticated against?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the recipiant of the email is inside your GAL ? (I see info@lldynamo... in example) If no, then configure your exchange to accept only mail for user inside your GAL, as it can be a way to relay

Comment: No they are not within the GAL. Even if it was, I would want the authenticated users to be able to do that.

Comment: Inside your office Outlook does not use the SMTP protocol to talk to Exchange, usually the SMTP traffic always come from outside your organisation. So you accept a mail for another domain in your Exchange ?

Comment: I know, but we actually do relay for another domain and also there are other services that directly use SMTP instead of outlook. I can't do that.

Comment: 1-) You've got the ip address of the sender in your log -> It's a botnet, this is simply an example, there are hundreds like this.
2-) It appears that the username of the user sending the email is in your capture. -> It's not an AD user. I'm also looking to find what it's authenticating against, what is it if not AD?

Comment: rcpt to does say "unable to relay" for other domains when I test without the authentication. I have not tested with authentication but I'm going to test it soon, with the same password and with another random password and see the difference in the result. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm not aware that you can authenticate against Exchange with a user account that isn't in AD. How would you authenticate to Exchange with a user account that didn't exist in AD? Have you queried your AD user accounts to look for the account in the log? Assuming the username in the log is encoded, you'll need to decode it first.

Comment: Ah, I assumed it was not encoded given the fact that there was a plaintext "Pass" next to it. It actually translates into a username. I'm going to ask the user to change the password and see if it fixes it. That was what made me ask the question here. Thanks a lot. I should stop assuming.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help. This should work to decode the username - https://www.base64decode.org

Answer (score 0):

Check your tracking logs - they show "from" addresses in readable format and also you can see the subject to know you're getting the right account login.  You may also be able to see emails in the outbound queue if they are stacking up rapidly.

Comment: Check the comment :) the user got answered already